# How do kernel get to know when a USB device goes to low power mode by itself (not initiated by host)?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, usb, device-driver

One USB device has the ability to go into low power mode(supports suspend and resume).

The host also can initiate suspend and resume for the device, in this case, the host knows about device state.

Scenario is:

- Device initiate low power mode.
- Host driver Want to access this information about low power state of device
- How can a driver get this information from Linux Kernel?

Comment: sysfs can provide this info, see here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/power-management.html

Comment: Thanks, @ApriOri, here they have mentioned how you can enable and disable Remote wake up, suspend and resume ability and how you can set autosuspend_delay_ms. These are all configuration about the behavior of USB device. I need the status of the device when it is in low power mode initiated by the device itself. ..... So that I can control resume of the device. There is no information about controlling Resume process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per USB specification, a USB device cannot suspend a link to USB host. Only host can suspend a link. Also suspend(U3) is not same as low power mode(U1/U2). A device can start switching to low power mode by negotiating with host but not suspend.

Now lets consider you meant low power mode (U1/U2), then host driver has no way to know when the ports are switching to low power mode initiated by device as there will be no event for that. You need to monitor the link state your self to see if the link has switched to low power mode.

As far as I know, there is one API which is used to to get link state of device connected to a hub.

```
static void xhci_hub_report_link_state(struct xhci_hcd *xhci,
                u32 *status, u32 status_reg)
```

This API you can use to track the link state of a device which is connected via external hub. But there is no API which can be used to read root hub port link state. If host controller driver exposes any interface, then that can be used.

See the dwc3 controller code which exposes a debugfs interface which can be used to read link state.

path - usb/dwc3/debugfs.c

API -

```
static int dwc3_link_state_show(struct seq_file *s, void *unused)
```

PS - I have considered you have XHCI controller. But its almost same for EHCI controller too. Device can never suspend USB link.

Comment: Thanks A Lot, :-), @Shaibal, Yes I used Suspend|Resume terminology that may change the scope when we talk about from different perspectives like from USB and From Host Driver. But Yes I meant to Power mode initiation that is in the capability of USB device. As you told host driver can not recognize these changes.

Comment: Can you @Shaibal help me to know, how I can send SET FEATURE command (U1/U2 Enable) from Host driver (from kernel not from firmware), so that I can disable this feature for specific OS for which I am using this driver. [Help me If I am using the wrong terminology again]

In specific, I want to send USB command from Kernel Driver.

Comment: You need to send CLEAR_FEATURE to disable the U1/U2 feature. You can write an application in host to do a control transfer to your device and for that libusb is the best. Follow https://github.com/tytouf/libusb-cdc-example/blob/master/cdc_example.c as an example of libusb.

Comment: Remember that you can only send clear_feature(U1/U2) only when the device is in configured state